# Sending email message from SAS Enterprice Guide

Tags: sas

toI have some data set, lets call it "FORMESSAGE"

[image]

I need to create a loop that will send text from data set "FORMESSAGE", variable MEssage to Email.
For example text "Thank you" to mail "God1@gmail.com",
second letter text "Thank you very much" to   God2@gmail.com and etc (it can be mere than 100)

Here is what I have now:

```
filename outbox email
               to=(***)
               type='text/html'
               subject='MEssage'
               from='sender@gmail.com';


      ods html body=outbox rs=none;

      proc print data=???;
      run;

      ods html close;
```

How to create loop for this case? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `'!EM_...!'` directives in a datastep :

```
filename em email type='text/html' from="sender@gmail.com" ;
data _null_ ;
  file em ;
  set formassage ;
  put '!EM_NEWMSG!' ;
  put '!EM_TO!' email ;
  put massage ;
  put '!EM_SEND!' ;
  put '!EM_ABORT!' ;
run ;
```

https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002592795.htm

Embedding HTML :

```
filename em email type='text/html' from="sender@gmail.com" ;
data _null_ ;
  file em ;
  set formassage ;
  put '!EM_NEWMSG!' ;
  put '!EM_TO!' email ;

  put "<html><body style='font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;'>" ;
  put "<div style='border:1px solid;width:100%;'>" ;

  put "To " customer_name ;
  put "<p>Please find attached your latest message." ;

  put "<p>" massage ;

  put "<p>Have a nice day!" ;

  put "</div>" ;
  put "</body></html>" ;

  put '!EM_SEND!' ;
  put '!EM_ABORT!' ;
run ;
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but the letter comes with attachment. How can I send it other way? (not attachement) Is it possible to send html with style control? I led the simple example, I need to send number of variables to a target user.(some kind of statement)